# Taglib sets album picture but gives seg fault

Tags: c++, c, taglib

I'm trying to set an album art in an .mp3 with TagLib but i get an error 11 (seg fault) and i can't seem to find a solution.
This is my code so far:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File mp3_file(filename.c_str());
TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *mp3_tag;

mp3_tag = mp3_file.ID3v2Tag(true);
TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame picture;
picture.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
picture.setDescription("Cover");
picture.setType(TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover);

std::ifstream image(image_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
const auto fileSize = image.tellg();
image.seekg(0);
TagLib::ByteVector image_data((unsigned int) fileSize, 0);
image.read(image_data.data(), fileSize);
image.close();
picture.setPicture(image_data);
mp3_tag->addFrame(&picture);
mp3_file.save();
```

The image is a .jpg so the MIME type is correct.
When the code reaches the line `mp3_tag->addFrame(&picture);` it exists with seg fault, the strange thing is that the image gets set to the .mp3 file so i don't understand what might cause this error.
I tried searching for a possible cause by looking at some C# and Ruby code using this library as well but i can't find a solution that won't result in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never came across TagLib, however, reading [the documentation](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Tag.html#ae090718d9acff1341530aa6438759b40), the `TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame picture;` variable needs to be allocated on a heap, since the `TagLib::ID3v2::Tag::addFrame(Frame* frame)` function will take ownership for the frame, thus is responsible for freeing the memory.
The segfault happens because it tries to free the memory (`picture` variable) allocated on a stack.

What you probably want is something like:

```
[...]
std::ifstream image(image_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
const auto fileSize = image.tellg();
image.seekg(0);
TagLib::ByteVector image_data((unsigned int) fileSize, 0);
image.read(image_data.data(), fileSize);
image.close();

TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame* picture = new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame(image_data);
mp3_tag->addFrame(&picture);
mp3_file.save();
[...]
```

Comment: marking your answer as correct, that was the main problem of my implementation just letting everyone that might come across this question know that after ```image.close();``` to set correctly the image it's needed to do ```auto *picture = new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame();``` then set the MIME type, the description and the type as i did in the original question and finally use ```picture->setPicture(image_data);``` and ```mp3_tag->addFrame(picture);``` to set the picture in the mp3 file.

Comment: @JohnSmith Cool, glad it helped!